Toast not popping up in expo react native
i created a toast using react-native-flash-message in expo react native, then i designed the way i wanted the toast to look like, and added a handleToast method to popup the toast when i call it, the problem is that it doesn't work, i tried adding z index to see if that is what is causing it not to work but same issue.
here is my code:
export function handleToast(text: string, type?: "error" | "success") {
  console.log("e dey");
  
  showMessage({
    message: "",
    duration: 5000,
    style: [
      styles.flashMessage,
      {
        borderLeftWidth:5,
        borderLeftColor:type == "error" ? Color.mRed : "#47CE75",
       
      },
    ],
    icon: () => (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          width: "100%",
         

          // backgroundColor: "blue",
        }}>

        <AntDesign
          name={type == "error" ? "warning" : "checkcircleo"}
          size={14}
          color={type == "error" ? Color.mRed : "#47CE75"}
          style={{ marginRight: "1%", textAlign: "center" }}
        />
        <Text
          style={{ color:  "#E8E8E8", fontSize: 12, textAlign:"center", fontFamily:Font.quicksandRegular}}>
          {text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    ),
  });
}

export default function Toast() {
  return <FlashMessage  position="top" />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flashMessage: {
    borderRadius: 12,
    // opacity: 0.8,

    // borderColor: "#222",
    margin: 12,
    marginTop: "10%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",

    backgroundColor: "#1A1A17",
    // borderColor:"#3C3C3A",
    borderWidth:1,
    zIndex:1000000
    
    // paddingLeft:"30%"
  },
});

this is where i am trying to use the toast:
return (
    <Div>
      <View style={styles.navCont}>
        <View style={styles.nav}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ position: "absolute", left: 0 }}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("BottomTabNavigator");
            }}>
            <Feather name="chevron-left" size={28} color={Color.white} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

      </View>
      <View style={styles.textWrap}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <View style={styles.indicator}>
            <View style={styles.innerIndicator}></View>
          </View>
          <P style={styles.p}>From available balance</P>
        </View>
        <H1 style={styles.headerText}>{formatter.format(Number(money))} USDT</H1>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.cardModal}>
        {Number(money) < route.params.total ? (
          <>
        <Button
          styleling={styles.btn}
          Title="Top up balance"
          textcolor="white"
          css={{ marginBottom: "1%", height: (15 * width) / 100 }}
          onPress={() => {
          consolo.log("")
          }}
        />
          <P
            style={{
              fontSize: 11,
              lineHeight: 15,
              fontFamily: Font.LibreFranklinMedium,
              color: Color.textMediumGray,
            }}>
            Your available balance is insufficient to purchase this token,{"\n"}
            please top up your balance.
          </P>
          </>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: (5 * height) / 100,
          width: "100%",
        }}>
        <Button
          Title="Pay now"
          onPress={() => {
            
            handleToast("somthign")
            ;
          }}
        />
      </View>
      {/* <Toast /> */}

      <Modal
        visible={showPinInput}
        animationType="slide"
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setShowPinInput(false);
        }}>
        <Div>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.header,
              {
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderBottomColor: Color.lineColor,
                width: "100%",
                paddingLeft: "5%",
                height: (6 * height) / 100,
              },
            ]}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                setShowPinInput(false);
              }}>
              <Ionicons name="close" size={30} color="white" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.textWrap}>
            {/* @ts-ignore */}
            <H1 style={[styles.headerText, { marginLeft: 0, fontSize: 16 }]}>
              Enter PIN
            </H1>
            {/* @ts-ignore */}
            <P style={[styles.p, { paddingLeft: 0, fontSize: 14 }]}>
              Enter your 4-digit PIN to perform this action.
            </P>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.pinContainer}>
            {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, index) => (
              <View
                key={index}
                style={[
                  styles.pinDot,
                  {
                    backgroundColor:
                      pin.length > index ? Color.primary : Color.textMediumGray,
                  },
                ]}></View>
            ))}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.keyboardContainer}>
            <View style={styles.keyboard}>
              {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, null, 0].map((digit, index) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  disabled={pin.length === 4}
                  key={index}
                  onPress={() =>
                    digit !== null ? enterDigit(digit.toString()) : null
                  }
                  style={styles.key}>
                  <H1 style={styles.keyText}>{digit}</H1>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ))}
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={clearLastDigit} style={styles.key}>
                <FontAwesome5 name="backspace" size={20} color="white" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.bottomItem}>
            <Link
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("ForgotPinScreen");
              }}
              Title={
                <P
                  style={{
                    color: Color.primary,
                    fontFamily: Font.LibreFranklinold,
                  }}>
                  Forgot Pin?
                </P>
              }
            />
          </View>
          {loader && <Loader />}
        </Div>
      </Modal>
      <Toast/>

    </Div>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navCont: {
    width,
    height: (15 * width) / 100,
    borderBottomWidth: 1.2,
    borderColor: Color.lightGray,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  nav: {
    width: "85%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    // backgroundColor: "red",
    height: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  textWrap: {
    marginTop: "10%",
    width: "85%",
    minHeight: (15 * width) / 100,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: "2%",
    marginLeft: "9%",
  },
  p: {
    fontSize: (4.1 * width) / 100,
    lineHeight: 20,
    color: Color.textPrimary,
    paddingRight: "5%",
    paddingLeft: "3%",
  },
  cardModal: {
    width: "85%",
    height: (15 * height) / 100,
    alignSelf: "center",
    // alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: "5%",
  },
  indicator: {
    width: 18,
    height: 18,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderRadius: 9,
    borderWidth: 1.5,
    borderColor: Color.seaBlue,
  },
  innerIndicator: {
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: Color.seaBlue,
  },
  btn: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff1a",
  },
  header: {
    width: "96%",
    height: (10 * height) / 100,
    // backgroundColor: "red",
    alignSelf: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingRight: "5%",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  bottomItem: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: "5%",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  iconStyle: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  pinContainer: {
    width: "85%",
    alignSelf: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  pinDot: {
    width: 9,
    height: 9,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: Color.textMediumGray,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  keyboardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  keyboard: {
    width: "80%",
    // backgroundColor: "red",
    height: (60 * height) / 100,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: "5%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
  },
  key: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    margin: 5,
  },
  keyText: {
    fontSize: 24,
  },
});

the Div component is just a safe view inside a GestureHandlerRootView, if you need any additional information to help me i will gladly drop in  the comments
